# What is a RP Paket in a tcpdump log?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpip, tcp, tcpdump

I have a tcpdump log with the following entry:

> 14:53:31.428570 IP 10.4.65.65.16666 > 192.168.201.10.80: RP 587:687(100) ack 48545454154 win 0

My Problem is that i have never seen an RP paket before.. What does it mean?

Is it kind of a reset paket?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Flags are some combination of S (SYN),
>   F (FIN), P (PUSH),  R  (RST),  W (ECN 
>   CWR)  or  E  (ECN-Echo),  or a single
>   `.' (no flags).

© man tcpdump

So, here you have TCP packet with RST (which means that it actually is a reset packet) and PUSH flags set.

Answer (score 0):

In network related situations I only know RP as "Rendevouz Point" in Protocol Independent Multicast (Sparse Mode) - PIM-SM.

Unfortunately I am not sure about what the packets would look like. You might want to compare the ports or take a decision based on the environment you recorded the tcpdump. (These packages are not that common AFAIK)